# jqgrid function behaving odd in coldfusion 2018

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have this function

```
<cffunction name="queryConvertForJQGRID" access="package" returntype="any" output="false">
        <cfargument name="q" type="query" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="page" type="numeric" required="no" default="1">
        <cfargument name="rows" type="numeric" required="no" default="500">
        <cfset var result = structnew()>
        <cfset var rowStruct = structnew()>
        <cfset var col = "">
        <cfset result["page"] = arguments.page>
        <cfset result["total"] = ceiling(arguments.q.TotalrecordCount/arguments.rows)>
        <cfset result["records"] = arguments.q.TotalrecordCount>
        <cfset result["rows"] = arraynew(1)>
        <cfset queryDeleteColumn(arguments.q,'TotalrecordCount')>
        <cfset queryDeleteColumn(arguments.q,'rowNum')>
        <cfif server.coldfusion.productname eq 'lucee'>
            <cfset columnLabels = QueryColumnArray(arguments.q)>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset columnLabels = arguments.q.columnList.listToArray()>
        </cfif>
        <cfloop query="#arguments.q#">
            <cfset rowStruct = [:]><!--- Tada an ordered struct --->
            <cfloop array="#columnLabels#" item="col">
               <cfset rowStruct[col] = arguments.q["#col#"]>
            </cfloop>
            <cfset arrayappend(result.rows, rowStruct)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfreturn result />
    </cffunction>
```

works perfect with lucee, but in coldfusion 2018, every row is showing the value as comma separated and all rows are in all rows. that is very weird

Screenshot

here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/rcltqm

so i have like this

```
<cfset retJSON = queryConvertForjQGrid(local.returnQry, arguments.page, arguments.rows)>
        <cfdump var="#retJSON#" abort>
```

and the structure is returned like this

https://prnt.sc/rcniba

Comment: That function doesn't execute with a standard query.  Use `queryNew()` to include an sample query that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You probably want an array of ordered structs. It would be useful to have a screenshot of data in and data out.

Comment: here is the screenshot
https://prnt.sc/rcltqm

Comment: Can you show a sample of the JSON that's generated? That's what ultimately powers the grid widget.

Comment: so i have like this

Comment: question updated with what i get